# Paste operation while running Parallels Desktop causes Yosemite to hang

Tags: macos, performance, copy-paste

I don't know exactly how/when/why this behavior started, but recently whenever I perform a paste operation (mostly this happens in a browser, from one tab to another), my entire system (2013 MBP running Yosemite) will hang for a number of seconds (~30-60sec).

I'll copy some text from one page then paste it in another (e.g. a form, a gmail compose window, etc.) and on the paste operation, instead of the text getting pasted, the mouse cursor becomes the circular, colorful "waiting" icon. At this point the entire system appears to be "hanging", although I can move the cursor. For example, during the hang, even my Parallels Windows VM is unresponsive. When the system returns from the hang, the text is not pasted.

I also tested this with a non-browser application (Notes) and it still causes a hang, so that's why I'm implicating the OS.

This is obviously a fairly serious and limiting bug, so your help is appreciated.

edit 1: I tried disabling the auto-correct spelling setting (under Keyboard), but this doesn't appear to help.

edit 2: **This appears to be caused by Parallels Desktop**. I shut down my VM and closed Parallels Desktop and the issue goes away. After restarting the VM, the issue persists. Parallels has fairly tight OS integration, so this does not surprise me. I'll take this up with Parallels and report back if there is a solution.

Comment: I suppose the question now is this a CPU hog, or simply I/O blocking. I would recommend installing any one of the CPU monitors you can find on the App Store and seeing if you're pegging CPU.

Comment: Thanks @MauryMarkowitz - I believe I have narrowed down the cause of the issue to Parallels Desktop (see edit 2).

Comment: @Kohanz PD 9 or PD 10?

Comment: @klanomath PD 10. I am wondering if this is the issue (http://kb.parallels.com/en/113893). I am running Visual Studio in my VM.

Comment: @Kohanz i think it's not restricted to VS. I have those hangs during copy pasting from WindowsVM2Mac & MacVM2Mac or accessing a shared PD folder without VS installed at all. It's no problem if i access a real network share.

Comment: @klanomath Are you talking about C/P files? I'm referring to simple text, from one Mac app to another, simply while the VM is running in the background.

Comment: @Kohanz probably different symptoms of the same problem. Only Yosemite (real machine or VM) and PD10. The hangs also last between 30 and 60 seconds. Mavericks and PD 10 doesn't have this problem as long as no Yosemite VM is involved...